# Why my request get stuck when mule is secured by HTTP Basic Authentication?

Tags: http, authentication, spring-security, mule

I am new to mule, and I configured mule security with HTTP Basic Authentication as following:

```
<spring:beans>
<!-- Setup authentication -->
  <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
   <ss:authentication-provider user-service-ref="appAuthService">
 </ss:authentication-provider>
</ss:authentication-manager>
<spring:bean id="appAuthService" class="org.jamee.demo.mule.rest.AppAuthService" />
<ss:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
</spring:beans>

<flow name="muleFlow1" doc:name="muleFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" path="rest"
 doc:name="HTTP">
 <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" /> 
</http:inbound-endpoint>
<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
 <component class="org.jamee.demo.mule.rest.WeatherService" />
</jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

It works fine when I debug in Mule Studio, but when I export it as zip package and put it in app/ of mule-standalone-3.4.0, and request the rest API by browser, it prompts me user and password, I input the right one, and it accepts, but the browser is busy and no response output, seems the mule get stuck.

When I remove the:<mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>,It response the right output immediately.

Log seems normal:

```
INFO  2013-08-08 09:07:42,870 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'demo.rest'                                      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
八月 08, 2013 9:07:45 上午 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.6 03/25/2011 01:14 PM'
INFO  2013-08-08 09:07:45,801 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'demo.rest'                                  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2013-08-08 09:07:45,803 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener:

**********************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* demo.rest                                     * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

INFO  2013-08-08 09:07:45,806 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Can you share with us the logs of the app?

Comment: see my edit, the log seems normal

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I checked the code carefully, I found that: I import a wrong class: edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays, when I changed to: java.util.Arrays, it works fine!
I am not sure how the edu.emory Arrays implemented.